# How to get starting with Bootstrap notify

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-notify

What part am I missing in order to make bootstrap notify to be working?

I just can't find the error.

> jsbin.com/tagohopofo/edit?html,js,output

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.notify("Hello World");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
 
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-notify/0.2.0/css/bootstrap-notify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-notify/0.2.0/css/bootstrap-notify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-notify/0.2.0/css/styles/alert-blackgloss.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Thank you!

Comment: >4k rep and still post links instead of code? Is this a joke?

Comment: If you want code, I can provide it

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You need to update version of your **jquery** to latest:

Here you can see live demo: https://output.jsbin.com/seqomanera

https://jsbin.com/wapuwuvuze/edit?html,js,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-notify/0.2.0/css/bootstrap-notify.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-notify/0.2.0/css/styles/alert-bangtidy.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-notify/0.2.0/css/styles/alert-blackgloss.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-notify/0.2.0/js/bootstrap-notify.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $.notify("Hello World");
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```